# How can I reinit docker layers?

Tags: docker

Using docker under Kubuntu 18 I got out of free space on the device.
I run commands to clear space:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)

docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker-compose down --remove-orphans
docker system prune --force --volumes
```

As I was still of free space  opened /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ directory and
deleted a lot of subdirectories ubder it.

After that I got error :

```
$ docker-compose up -d --build
Creating network "master_default" with the default driver
ERROR: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/36af81b800ebb595a24b6c724318c1126932d2bfae61e2c98bfc65a203b2b928: no such file or directory
```

1. Looks like that is not a good way to free space. Which way isd good in my case?
2. If there is a way to reinit my docker apps?

Thanks!

Comment: What version are you using? Anyway, could you try restarting your docker daemon?

Comment: docker-compose version 1.17.1, build unknown
I restarted the OS - and the same error

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit, I mean your docker version. Could you try running `docker system prune -a`?

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Could you please explain the command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/var/lib/docker/overlay2/` is where docker stores the image layers.

Now, `docker system prune -a` removes all the unused images, stopped containers and the build cache if I'm not wrong.

One advice, since you are building images, check docker buildkit. I know docker-compose added support for it, but I don't know if your version supports that. To make it short, building your images will be way faster.

Answer (score 3):

> As I was still of free space opened `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/` directory and deleted a lot of subdirectories ubder it.

At this point, the docker filesystem has been corrupted. To repair, the best you can do is backup anything you want to save, particularly any volumes, stop the docker engine (`systemctl stop docker`), delete the entire docker filesystem (`rm -rf /var/lib/docker`), and restart docker (`systemctl start docker`).

At that point the engine will be completely empty without any images, containers, etc. You'll need to pull/rebuild your images and recreate the containers you were running. Hopefully that's as easy as a `docker-compose up`.

Comment: Perfect. Worked without a problem. I simply restarted and it started without a problem. Thanks.